# How to use nested ConcurrentHashMap in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have a data structure `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>`
Now I need to add tread safety to this data structure, which one should I use?

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>
```

or

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>>
```

What's the difference between these two?

Comment: the former only makes the outer map threas-safe, the inner makes both thread-safe.

Comment: if the first one doesn't guarantee inner `HashMap` thread-safe, then how come a plain `CurrentHashMap<String, String>` to be thread safe? Applying same logic, the second `String` should not thread safe?

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` hurantees thread safety on its own operations. This does not apply for elements of it if they are not thread-safe since you could do non-thread-safe operations on the elements of the `ComcurrentHashMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) is thread-safe. That means that every operation you perform *on* a `ConcurrentHashMap` is thread-safe as well. However, this neither guarantees that your code using `ConcurrentHashMap` is thread safe nor that the elements of the `ConcurrentHashMap` are thread safe.

If you have a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>`, it would be thread safe as long as you don't change any inner `HashMap`s after inserting (immutable `Map`s would likely be a better option in that case) or make sure that operations on the inner `HashMap` are synchronized in some other way. So basically, you have a thread-safe `Map` containing non-thread-safe values.

```java
ConcurrentHashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> yourMap = ...;
//assume the Map is populated with some values and accessed from multiple threads
HashMap<String, String> innerMap = yourMap.get("someKey");//thread-safe
//innerMap.put("someKey","someValue");//NOT thread-safe
```

However, if you have a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>>`, operations on both the outer and inner `Map` will be thread safe (and `String` is immutable hence thread-safe as well). So as long as you don't write any non-thread-safe code around it, it will be thread safe.

Note that for best flexibility, you might want to use the interfaces instead of concrete implementations:

```java
Map<String, Map<String, String>> yourMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
//inserting like this
yourMap.put("key",new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
//do not insert non thread-safe Maps
//yourMap.put("key",new HashMap<>());//DON'T, the value will not be thread-safe
```

Using an interface instead of a concrete implementation allows you to change the type later easily and also allows to use with other APIs.

If you want to express concurrency in the static type, you could use [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) instead of [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html).

```
ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentMap<String, String>> yourMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Comment: Seems like I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Why the use of the word “static” in that last sentence?

Comment: The "static type" or "compile-time type" is the type of the variable while the "dynamic type" or "runtime type" is the type of the actual object. E.g. `Map<String,String> someMap = new HashMap<>();` has the static type `Map` and dynamic type `HashMap`.